# jQuery - ajax request not hitting .error state

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a pretty simple ajax call that will hit the success state but won't hit the error state it just throws a 404. The odd thing is this works just fine in IE but not in firefox or chrome. If I change the data type to **text** it works fine in firefox but not IE. Any help is appreciated!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://www.google.com',       
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback'
}).success(function(){
    console.log("success");
}).error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

Comment: Try 'fail' function instead of 'error'

Comment: `success` and `error` are jquery ajax options properties. You're looking for `done` and `fail`;

Answer (score 0):

Success and error do not exist. You need to call the JS functions done and fail instead. Also, for best practices use console.error instead of console.log on your fail condition.

Try the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://www.google.com',       
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback'
}).done(function(){
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.error("error");
});
```